# Custom Input Field when select shipping method on frontend - Magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-method

I want to create a Custom Shipping Method on Checkout Page and when customer will select that Shipping Method, it should display a new text field and allows customer to enter in the text field. That text field value should be shown everywhere in the admin, emails etc.

Can anyone please me in this or any right direction to achieve this.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module. Here you have an easy example to create a new shipping method:
https://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

To add the field you told, you should add a new column to database. Depending on the content of this field and how you will retrieve this information you could add this column to sales_flat_order or sales_flat_shipment.
Here you have an example to do this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/adding-custom-fields-to-sales-flat-order

Adding this feature to the custom shipping method should be enough.

Hope it helps. Regards.